# Cleaning Curated Data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, curated-data

I am preparing data consisting of `temperature` and `pressure` values from each country in the world using the following code.

```
worldTemp = 
QuantityMagnitude[
WeatherData[#, "Temperature"] & /@ CountryData["Countries"]];

worldPressure = 
QuantityMagnitude[
WeatherData[#, "Pressure"] & /@ CountryData["Countries"]];

Data = 
MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {worldPressure, worldTemp}];
```

How do you omit the rows containing `{QuantityMagnitude[Missing["NotAvailable"]]}`from the data set. Then I need to export the data into an excel file. Is that possible?

Comment: `Select[Data, NumericQ[#[[1]]] && NumericQ[#[[2]]] &]` ?

Comment: No I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Some rows contain a missing value as well as a number. For example: {{na,2},{6,2},{5,na},{na,na}}

Comment: In 11.3 I only get pairs, either of numbers or of `Missing` messages, as members of `Data`. To keep only rows with entirely numeric data, you might try `Select[Data, Apply[And, Map[NumericQ[#] &, Flatten[#]] &[#]] &]`

Comment: Have you seen `DeleteMissing`. It should do what you want, but whatever you do to get rid of the missing values, you should do it **before** trying to extract numeric values with `QuantityMagnitude`...